# Movieclip or vector data for flashpunk?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

Hello is there a way to use a movieclip for a graphic in the flashpunk library?

Normally we would embed a .png image and declare it as a class and then we would make the graphic of the entity class become this new image.

```
[Embed(source = "../img/QButton.png")] private var m_QButtonClass:Class;


this.graphic = new Image(m_QButtonClass);
```

I tried this:

```
[Embed(source='Player.swf', symbol='PlayerSymbol')] private var _someVector:Class;

this.graphic = new Image(_someVector);
```

Is there a way to load the vector data/movie clip data from Adobe profressional cs6 using flashpunk ?

Comment: Short answer: no. FlashPunk handles animation itself, and there's no support for vector data as far as I know.

Comment: @user2321004 You should be able to export a MovieClip as a spritesheet to use though